# How to digitally sign a PDF in Android device?

Tags: android, pdf, itext, digital-signature, keystore

Is it possible to digitally sign a PDF in Android device? If answer is yes, how do I sign a PDF using iText in Android? How can I create a keystore for self signed mode in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to sign a PDF on Android. You can use iText on Android or you can use [PDFBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-pdf.php) package of our SecureBlackbox (now released). For iText signing sample see the bottom-right of [this page](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=12) (they offer several samples there).

Comment: Hi Eugene, do you know if there are libraries/vendors out there that provide such a PDF-signing library for iOS and Android together? Especially we are interested in signing/verifying PDF/A documents and P7M files.

Comment: @muetzenflo SecureBlackbox is available on both Android and iOS, with Java, C++ and .NET (via Xamarin) editions.